# What would be the most secure solution for a very simple user control in PHP?

Tags: php, security, user-controls

I was wondering what would be the most simple but secure method for the following user control logic:

- 1 user/site (no database involved)
- User logs in from a login page but not redirected to an admin panel, yet upon login the user gets some advanced rights directly on the frontend (delete/edit/etc links)

Questions:

- How safe it is to store the username and (cleartext) password in a config file? I am aware that it probably isn't the best way, but the password should be ideally in cleartext form for convenient editing based on a config file (phpMyAdmin does the same in its config.inc.php file, so I assume it's more or less okay).
- What would be the best/safest way to follow the logged in user on the site? My current solution checks the user's status and IP on every pageload (logged_in session is TRUE and IP session is the user's IP, both generated on initial login)? Is that fine?
- What else should I keep my eye on?

Thank you for your answer(s) in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing password in plain text is pretty much a no-no. You should hash it using a secure hash (md5 for example is not secure), and 'salt' it (that is, prepend or append a 'secret' string to the password before hashing it - otherwise, finding the password from the hash is still relatively easy, especially when the password is a common one). If you don't want to make a full change-password page, you can whip up a little helper script to hash the password and not store it on the web server; when you need a new password, you run it and paste its output into the config file.

Other things to watch out for (common attacks):

- SQL injection (POST or GET values inserted into queries; malicious input can break your queries in interesting ways). Use PDO and parametrize all your database inputs, and you should be good.
- Path traversal. If you read filenames, or parts of filenames, from `$_POST` or `$_GET` or any other user input, inserting malicious values can send files to the client that weren't intended to be public.
- Script injection. Similar to path traversal: Any `include`, `require` or `eval` statement that takes dynamic input is a potential hook that attackers can use to inject their own PHP code into your application (e.g. if you have `include $_GET['page'];`, then someone can use this to include a script from somewhere else)
- Cross-site scripting. If you have any dynamic HTML on your page, make sure nobody can abuse this to put scripts or iframes on a page; otherwise, someone could use this to read session cookies and take over another user's session.
- Man-in-the-middle: Sending login credentials over plain HTTP means anyone with a network sniffer on the same LAN, as well as anyone with access to any router between the client and the server, can easily follow the HTTP conversation and extract the credentials. Even if the credentials are secured, the same goes for the session cookie, so it's best to serve everything over HTTPS once a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to store the password as a hash. You never know who gets access to the ftp. Or if the PHP server goes down all PHP files will be shown plain-text. It's hardly an effort to stored it hashed but it can save you a lot of potential headaches.

The method of following the user seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you also made sure that your config file with the password can under no circumstances be accessed by a public user. It's a good idea to completely deny web access to that file, using a .htaccess file in your config folder.

Also, I would recommend to store a hash instead of a cleartext password.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to database storage is file storage. And the most elegant way of storing stuff into a file is using an XML format, which can be parsed using XPath queries. See an example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp.

I never worked with the XPath on PHP and never worked with it raw (used the methods and objects which were implementig it).

Sadly I can not give you more details as I am also looking into this. I really think there might be a matter of speed and overall security (Your database is protected by a user and a password while the XML file or any file isn't).

a line can look like this

```
<user username="username" password="edf53kqwolebng653fgism33grhloi76">
      <name>John doe</name>
      <rights>
           <module name="one">0010</module>
           <module name="two">1111</module>
      </rights>
</user>
```

the figures represent the Create Read Update Delete rights (1 has, 0 doesn't) so if a user has only reading rights the access key will be 0100 (considering CRUD order).

Mainly all you have to do is load that info into the session once logged in.

Hope it helps.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put the password file outside the web root (e.g., in `/etc`) to prevent accidentally serving it.

If you use a hash, [use bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). But remember that an attacker with full access can trojan the login page to get the password the next time you log in.

Secure the login page with SSL to prevent man-in-the-middle.